# UPDATE table A, then INSERT new values into table B (with history log of what was updated)

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I am looking for a way to updated some values on specified SQL tables (`tr__Transaction`) and insert some values to history table (`tr_History`) with description what was updated (string value) AT THE SAME TIME (in a single query) WITHOUT USING LOOP and TRIGGERS.

This is not database designed by me but it's existing one I am working on. For example I am updating existing records in (1,3,5) set with new value in `tr_ShippingMethodId` column.

3 rows are updated and now I want to insert into the `tr_History` table new records corresponding to my sample query.

This is my sample code:

```
DECLARE @tr__Transaction TABLE (tr_Id int, tr_ShippingMethodId int) -- table with transactions (online sale)

INSERT INTO @tr__Transaction (tr_Id, tr_ShippingMethodId) 
VALUES (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 9), (4, 8), (5, 0)

DECLARE @tr_History TABLE 
                    (
                        th_Id INT, 
                        th_TransId INT, 
                        th_Time DATETIME, 
                        th_Entry NVARCHAR(255)
                    ) -- table with history log (what changed made on transaction)

DECLARE @TrIdsToUpdate TABLE (trIdToUpdate int) -- table with ids to update

INSERT INTO @TrIdsToUpdate VALUES (1, 3, 5)

UPDATE @tr__Transaction 
SET tr_ShippingMethodId = 99 
WHERE tr_Id IN (SELECT trIdToUpdate FROM @TrIdsToUpdate)

INSERT INTO @tr_History (th_Id, th_TransId, th_Time, th_Entry) 
VALUES (spGetId(tr_History), 1, GETDATE(), 'Record 1 changed shipping method from 2 to 99')

INSERT INTO @tr_History (th_Id, th_TransId, th_Time, th_Entry) 
VALUES (spGetId(tr_History), 3, GETDATE(), 'Record 3 changed shipping method from 9 to 99')

INSERT INTO @tr_History (th_Id, th_TransId, th_Time, th_Entry) 
VALUES (spGetId(tr_History), 5, GETDATE(), 'Record 5 changed shipping method from 0 to 99')
```

In this query I had to use `spGetId(tr_History)` stored procedure which returns a free ID to insert (this is how it is designed originally).

I also used 3 `INSERT` commands to demonstrate what I want to achieve but using `@TrIdsToUpdate` table with single `INSERT`.

Any suggestion how to do it?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is very product specific.)

Comment: Why don't you want to use a trigger, and have you looked at t-sql `output` clause

Comment: i'm not sure this is sql server, stored procedures cannot be called like this. and functions usually need schema name.

Comment: @siggemannen You are right, I posted it wrongly formatted. It suppose to looks this way:
```
declare @id int;
exec spIdentyfikator 'tr_History', 1, @id OUTPUT
```

Comment: @Stu I don't want to use trigger because it will affect other updates. My update is out of the software which manage the database and I only try to do single job without software.

Comment: @jarlh this is Sello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `OUTPUT` clause.

```sql
DECLARE @tr__Transaction TABLE (tr_Id int PRIMARY KEY, tr_ShippingMethodId int); -- table with transactions (online sale)

INSERT INTO @tr__Transaction (tr_Id, tr_ShippingMethodId) 
VALUES (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 9), (4, 8), (5, 0);

DECLARE @tr_History TABLE 
                    (
                        th_Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
                        th_TransId INT, 
                        th_Time DATETIME, 
                        th_Entry NVARCHAR(255)
                    ); -- table with history log (what changed made on transaction)

DECLARE @TrIdsToUpdate TABLE (trIdToUpdate int PRIMARY KEY); -- table with ids to update

INSERT INTO @TrIdsToUpdate VALUES (1), (3), (5);

UPDATE @tr__Transaction
SET tr_ShippingMethodId = 99
  OUTPUT
    inserted.tr_ID,
    GETDATE(),
    CONCAT('Record ', inserted.tr_ID, ' changed shipping method from ', deleted.tr_ShippingMethodId, ' to ', inserted.tr_ShippingMethodId )
  INTO @tr_History
    (th_TransId, th_Time, th_Entry)
WHERE tr_Id IN (SELECT u.trIdToUpdate FROM @TrIdsToUpdate u);
```

I have no idea what your `spGetId` function is doing, but it's probably a bad idea and you should just use an `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE` column.

It would probably be wise to put primary keys on the table variables also, as shown, for performance reasons.

Comment: I have updated your code and added as my own answer, you can check it (code is workable)

Comment: I am now wondering if I can add value to the OUTPUT command which will be increased every OUTPUT command is fired, like `OUTPUT @th_Id = @th_Id + 1`

Comment: You don't need to, an `IDENTITY` column would sort that out. See edit. But if you really needed you could use a calculated `ROW_NUMBER` column https://dbfiddle.uk/gkb5JeZv

Comment: thank to your example I could modify my code and fix my problem. Thank you so much! Here is the final working code example: https://dbfiddle.uk/4N5pgAa- You can take a look. Maybe you know how can I disable output table from that example?

Comment: Yes that would work, just put back the `INTO` https://dbfiddle.uk/P2NDYxCf note that you cannot use `inserted.rn` as outlined here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/326842/output-clause-with-window-functions

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the `OUTPUT` command I could achieve my goal, thank you @Charlieface and @Stu

Here is working example:

```
DECLARE @tr__Transaction TABLE (tr_Id int, tr_ShippingMethodId int) -- table with transactions (online sale)
INSERT INTO @tr__Transaction (tr_Id, tr_ShippingMethodId) values (1, 2),(2, 2),(3, 9),(4, 8),(5, 0)
select * from @tr__Transaction

DECLARE @tr_History TABLE (th_Id INT, th_TransId INT, th_Time DATETIME, th_Entry NVARCHAR(255)) -- table with history log (what changed made on transaction)
select * from @tr_History

DECLARE @TrIdsToUpdate TABLE (trIdToUpdate int) -- table with ids to update
INSERT INTO @TrIdsToUpdate (trIdToUpdate) values (1), (3), (5)


UPDATE @tr__Transaction 
SET tr_ShippingMethodId = 99
OUTPUT null, inserted.tr_Id, GETDATE(), CONCAT( 'Record ', inserted.tr_Id, ' changed shipping method from ', deleted.tr_ShippingMethodId, ' to ', inserted.tr_ShippingMethodId )
INTO @tr_History (th_Id, th_TransId, th_Time, th_Entry)
WHERE tr_Id IN (SELECT trIdToUpdate FROM @TrIdsToUpdate)

select * from @tr__Transaction
select * from @tr_History
```

Comment: th_Id is created by executing this command `declare @id int; exec spIdentyfikator 'tr_History', 1, @id OUTPUT;` How can I use it with my code? I need to insert @id to the OUTPUT th_Id

Comment: What for? Why not just use an `IDENTITY` column `DECLARE @tr_History TABLE (th_Id INT, IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY...`

Comment: @Charlieface In this example I can change that but in original database I am reffering to I can't. `@th_id` is something I have to increase myself (no identity primary key option).

Comment: Then you need to show that in the question. I suggest you make a *new* question for that, as the above is already answered.

Comment: @Charlieface Yes I tried to make new qestion but after placing this question I am no longer able to add new question. I got message `Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from your account` :(. This is why I am trying to solve my last problem with that query here.

Comment: I've upvoted this question plus your answer so maybe the automatic ban will be lifted (you only get 1 question every 6 months if you're banned, until you get upvotes on one of them) See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans and try improve some of your old questions to get some upvotes.